# Childs should fill all width of parent but wrap if min-width is undercut

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a grid with a lots of childs. The HTML is simple as this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

The `.parent` has `width: 100%` and `max-width: 1024px`.

The `.child`s should

- be equally wide (even if the last row contains fewer elements)
- be as small as possible
- be at least as wide as their `min-width`
- fill all the space (in width) of their parent
- wrap if there is not enough space

I don't know the number of `child`s.

Do you have a solution? (I'm fine with solutions for Chrome, Safari and Firefox)

**UPDATE**

The parent should never scroll horizontally.

**UPDATE 2**

Example: `.parent` has a width of `1020px` and there are 11 childs with a `min-width` of `100px`. All elements should be `102px` wide; 10 elements in the first row and the 11th element in the second row.

Comment: if there is not enough space then Is it fine if horizontal scroll comes?

Comment: No, sorry, it is not. I will update my question.

Comment: Let say all child of 100px and there is 11 child Since it is greater than 1024px so what do you exactly want the behavior for the last child. Is it fine if it comes to a new line or it should overlap in that same line...

Comment: The last child should wrap, but the first 10 elements should be 102.4px wide. I've updated my question with an example.

Comment: Do all the children have the same min-width as each other?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, same min-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a CSS grid with [auto-sizing columns](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/) would fit here. I added colors to the example to make the divs visible.

```css
.parent {
    max-width: 1024px;
    display: grid;
    /*
      repeat(auto-fill, ...) creates as many columns as needed. 
        auto-fill: if there are not enough child elements to fill a row, they will be stretched to fill the row.
        auto-fit: the columns are created like if there are enough elements to fill a row. no stretching.
        
      minmax(100px, 1fr) limits the with of each column to a minimum of 100px and a maximum of 1fr (the whole width of a row)
    */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    
    /* Bonus tip: you can add a gap between the childs: */
    /* gap: 0.5em; */
}

.child {
    min-width: 100px;
}

/* Styles for demo purposes */

div {
    height: 2em;
}

.parent {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: auto;
}

.child {
    background-color: lightpink;
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```